# Python: a value of a variable changes unintentionally

Tags: python

I am working on a little project that involves working with and transforming coordinates and my code behaves in a way that I can't explain.
Example code:

```
koord = [[60,10],[70,18],[61,21],[69,11]]
min_X = [255,255]

for i in range(len(koord)):
    if koord[i][0]<min_X[0]:
        min_X=koord[i]
print(min_X)

for i in range(len(koord)):
    for j in range(2):
        koord[i][j]=koord[i][j] - min_X[j]
    print(min_X)
```

I expect it to always print [60, 10], but instead I get

```
[60, 10]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
```

Why does the `min_X` value change? It seams to redo the first for-loop but why?
Can someone explain why this happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: Because min_X is a reference to a list element, which changes.

Answer (score 1):

The first for loop assigns min_X to point to the first coordinate pair list, so now min_X === koord[0].  Then the second for loop updates koord[0], so min_X sees the same update since it is the same (list) object.

Here's a more contained example:

```py
a = [ 10 ]
b = a
a[0] -= b[0]
print(b)
# this returns [0]
```

Comment: Ok. But ist there a way to get it to not "link" them together, but keep them as seperate variables?

Comment: You can make a copy of the list, e.g., `newList = list(oldList)`.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/2366407 .